# Getting model when select option

Tags: angular

I would like to have the entire model in my `selected`-variable back, without loosing the `value`'s Id.

```
<label for="unit">Einheit</label>
          <select id="unit" name="unit" #unit="ngModel" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onDropdown()">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let i of Units" value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
          </select>
```

How to do it ?

Comment: just forget about change event and just use ngModelChange like onDropdown($event) (don't forget to pass event to get new value). Also you can do same think to get event on change event. It's like (change) = "onDropdown($event)"

Comment: @nevzatopcu thank you, but when I change it to `(ngModelChange)="onDropdown($event)"`, I still get the `id` passed through

Comment: just assign "i" value="{{i}}" and "selected" property  should be an object  instead a integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign just the variable i into option [ngValue] to get the entire object whent it been selected and  the "**selected**" property should be an object  any or strong typed

```
<label for="unit">Einheit</label>
  <select id="unit" name="unit" #unit="ngModel" required class="form-control" [ 
  (ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onDropdown()">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let i of Units" [ngValue]="i">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```